# Excel VBA: Code should check whether cell falls into criteria then paste to next active cell but not working

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble with my VBA Code.

So I have workbook with the following sheets:
 1. Sheet#1
 2. OFFLIMITS

First, I wanted to copy the expenses part. The idea is for the macro to check if cells in range (in Sheet#1) falls into criteria. If positive, then it will copy data to **OFFLIMITS** then proceed to the next cell in Sheet#1. This works fine.

Next, I wanted to check certain criteria again. This time, I'll be checking another column for the criteria. If positive, then excel will copy the data to offlimits.

It works. But I'm getting different result for the 3rd line.

Example:

```
          A             
   1     -1       
   2     -5       
   3      0       
   4     -3
```

I want a result of -1,-5 and -3. But I'm getting -1, -5 and 0. What might the wrong part in my code?

Thanks.

See code

```
Sub WHT()

    Dim origin      As Worksheet
    Dim destination As Worksheet
    Dim desrow      As Long
    Dim descol      As Long
    Dim descolstart As Long
    Dim origrow     As Long
    Dim origcol     As Long
    Dim rng         As range
    Dim C           As range
    Dim qual        As Integer
    Dim total       As Integer
    Dim descolnext  As Integer

    Set origin = Sheets("1")
    Set destination = Sheets("OFFLIMITS")
    desrow = 8
    descol = 1
    origrow = 17
    origcol = 32
    Set rng = origin.range("AI17:AI117")
    total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(origin.range("AI17:AI117"))
    descolstart = destination.Cells(desrow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    descolnext = descolstart + 1

    Dim whtRange As range
    Dim whtAmount As range

    Set whtRange = origin.range("AI17:AI117")

    For Each whtAmount In whtRange

        If whtAmount.Value = 30 Then

            destination.Cells(desrow, descolstart).Value = origin.range("C3").Value             'Vendor
            destination.Cells(desrow, descolstart + 1).Value = origin.range("C1").Value         'Transaction Date
            destination.Cells(desrow, descolstart + 2).Value = origin.range("C4").Value         'RefNumber
            destination.Cells(desrow, descolstart + 3).Value = origin.range("C6").Value         'Bill Due
            destination.Cells(desrow, descolstart + 4).Value = origin.range("C5").Value         'Terms
            destination.Cells(desrow, descolstart + 5).Value = origin.range("C7").Value         'Memo

            destination.Cells(desrow, descolstart + 6).Value = origin.Cells(origrow, 26).Value   'WHT Account
            destination.Cells(desrow, descolstart + 7).Value = origin.Cells(origrow, 23).Value   'WHT amount
            destination.Cells(desrow, descolstart + 8).Value = origin.Cells(origrow, 31).Value   'WHT Memo
            'no class for wht                                                                    'WHT class

            destination.Cells(desrow, descolstart + 15).Value = origin.range("C2").Value        'AP Account

            origrow = origrow + 1 'make next row origin
            desrow = desrow + 1 'make next row destination cell

        End If

    Next whtAmount

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've completely rewritten the code and made it work! See below.

```
Sub GenerateLoader()

Dim source          As Worksheet            'to be assigned as entry sheets
Dim destination     As Worksheet            'this is the OFFLIMITS worksheet
Dim dRow            As Long
Dim dColumn         As Long
Dim oRow            As Long
Dim oColumn         As Long
Dim dColumnStart    As Integer
Dim dColumnNext     As Integer
Dim RangeCheck      As range
Dim RangeTotal      As Integer
Dim RangeCounter    As range
Dim dRowStart       As Integer
Dim dRowNext        As Integer

Set source = Sheets("1")
oRow = 17
oColumn = 1

Set destination = Sheets("OFFLIMITS")
dRow = 8
dColumn = 1
dRowStart = destination.Cells(Rows.Count, dColumn).End(xlUp).Row + 1                 
'destination.Cells(desrow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
dRowNext = dColumnStart + 1
Set RangeCheck = source.range("Z17:Z117")
RangeTotal = WorksheetFunction.Sum(source.range("Z17:Z117"))

If RangeTotal > 0 Then

For Each RangeCounter In RangeCheck
    If RangeCounter > 0 Then

       ' destination.Cells(drowstart, dColumn).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 1).Value
       ' destination.Cells(drowstart, dColumn + 1).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 1).Value


                '** For the expense part

                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn).Value = source.range("C3").Value             'Vendor
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 1).Value = source.range("C1").Value         'Transaction Date
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 2).Value = source.range("C4").Value         'RefNumber
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 3).Value = source.range("C6").Value         'Bill Due
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 4).Value = source.range("C5").Value         'Terms
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 5).Value = source.range("C11").Value         'Memo

                If source.Cells(oRow, 5).Value = "Expenses" Then
                    destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 6).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 6).Value    'Expenses Account
                    destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 7).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 17).Value   'Expenses amount
                    destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 8).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 23).Value   'Expenses Memo
                    destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 9).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 10).Value    'Expenses class

                Else 'if item
                    destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 10).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 6).Value   'Item
                    destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 11).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 7).Value  'Item Qty
                    destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 12).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 23).Value  'Item Desc
                    destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 13).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 28).Value  'Item Cost
                    destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 14).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 10).Value   'Item Class

                End If

                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 15).Value = source.range("C2").Value      'AP Account
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 16).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 1).Value   'Line number

                dRowStart = dRowStart + 1

                '** end of expense part

                '#######################################################################################################

                '** for the withholding part

                If source.Cells(oRow, 13) = "Y" Then

                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn).Value = source.range("C3").Value             'Vendor
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 1).Value = source.range("C1").Value         'Transaction Date
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 2).Value = source.range("C4").Value         'RefNumber
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 3).Value = source.range("C6").Value         'Bill Due
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 4).Value = source.range("C5").Value         'Terms
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 5).Value = source.range("C11").Value         'Memo

                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 6).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 22).Value    'Expenses Account
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 7).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 19).Value   'Expenses amount
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 8).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 24).Value   'Expenses Memo
                'destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 9).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 10).Value   'Expenses class

                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 15).Value = source.range("C2").Value      'AP Account
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 16).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 1).Value      'Line number

                dRowStart = dRowStart + 1

                ElseIf source.Cells(oRow, 15) = "N" Then 'Do nothing

                End If

                '** end for withholding

                '#######################################################################################################


                '** for the VAT portion

                If source.Cells(oRow, 12) = "Input VAT Claimable" Then

                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn).Value = source.range("C3").Value                      'Vendor
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 1).Value = source.range("C1").Value                  'Transaction Date
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 2).Value = source.range("C4").Value                  'RefNumber
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 3).Value = source.range("C6").Value                  'Bill Due
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 4).Value = source.range("C5").Value                  'Terms
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 5).Value = source.range("C11").Value                 'Memo

                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 6).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 25).Value              'vat Account
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 7).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 18).Value              'vat amount
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 8).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 23).Value & "_VAT"     'Expenses Memo

                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 15).Value = source.range("C2").Value                 'AP Account
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 16).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 1).Value              'Line number

                dRowStart = dRowStart + 1

                '***

                ElseIf source.Cells(oRow, 12) = "Deferred VAT" Then

                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn).Value = source.range("C3").Value                      'Vendor
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 1).Value = source.range("C1").Value                  'Transaction Date
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 2).Value = source.range("C4").Value                  'RefNumber
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 3).Value = source.range("C6").Value                  'Bill Due
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 4).Value = source.range("C5").Value                  'Terms
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 5).Value = source.range("C11").Value                 'Memo

                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 6).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 25).Value              'Expenses Account
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 7).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 18).Value              'Expenses amount
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 8).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 23).Value & "_dVAT"    'Expenses Memo

                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 15).Value = source.range("C2").Value                 'AP Account
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 16).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 1).Value              'Line number

                dRowStart = dRowStart + 1

                '***

                ElseIf source.Cells(oRow, 12) = "Input VAT Expense" Then

                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn).Value = source.range("C3").Value                      'Vendor
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 1).Value = source.range("C1").Value                  'Transaction Date
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 2).Value = source.range("C4").Value                  'RefNumber
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 3).Value = source.range("C6").Value                  'Bill Due
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 4).Value = source.range("C5").Value                  'Terms
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 5).Value = source.range("C11").Value                 'Memo

                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 6).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 25).Value              'Expenses Account
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 7).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 18).Value              'Expenses amount
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 8).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 23).Value & "_VATX"    'Expenses Memo

                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 15).Value = source.range("C2").Value                 'AP Account
                destination.Cells(dRowStart, dColumn + 16).Value = source.Cells(oRow, 1).Value              'Line number

                dRowStart = dRowStart + 1

                ElseIf source.Cells(oRow, 12) = "Zero -rated" Then 'Do nothing

                ElseIf source.Cells(oRow, 12) = "Non -VAT" Then 'Do nothing

                End If

                '** end for VAT

                '#######################################################################################################


    End If

        oRow = oRow + 1

Next RangeCounter

End If

End Sub
```